# Getting records for today including all day events which span today

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have a list of appointments, with a startdate, enddate and allday flag.

I'd like to be able to output all records which fall on the current day.

Example records:

```
ID  Start,            End,             AllDay

1   27/11/2016 00:00  30/11/2016 00:00 true
2   30/11/2016 00:00  01/12/2016 00:00 true
3   30/11/2016 00:00  03/12/2016 00:00 true
4   30/11/2016 00:00  05/12/2016 00:00 true
5   01/12/2016 10:00  01/12/2016 15:00 false
6   02/12/2016 09:00  02/12/2016 11:00 false
```

Given this example data, and assuming the date is **01/12/2016** how do I get a query to output the following:

```
ID  Start,            End,             AllDay

2   30/11/2016 00:00  01/12/2016 00:00 true
3   30/11/2016 00:00  03/12/2016 00:00 true
4   30/11/2016 00:00  05/12/2016 00:00 true
5   01/12/2016 10:00  01/12/2016 15:00 false
```

I have 2 queries which both return output that is only partially correct:

```
start = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00"));
end = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00"));

var schedule = entity.Schedule.Where(x => x.Start >= start && x.End <= end && !x.AllDay)
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
                              .ToList();

var alldays = entity.Schedule.Where(x => x.Start <= start && x.End => start && x.AllDay)
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
                             .ToList()
```

Comment: How close ? What output do you get ?

Comment: Can you post your results? Open questions: Why would you serialize a DateTime to a String to parse it back into a DateTime? Why do you add a day to the date in question (currently: today) if you then compare the date with <= and >=? Wouldn't you remove the .AddDays or change the comparison with x.End and remove the = (less than, not less or equal than)?

Comment: Having slept on it, I have made a slight adjustment and got the results I expected to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var events= entity.Schedule.Where((
                x => x.Start <= start && x.End => start) || x.AllDay)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
                .ToList();
```

Is above works for you

Comment: Wouldn't that return _every_ entry that is scheduled for 'all day', whatever day that might be? Honestly, I think the AllDay flag is completely irrelevant for the purpose of this question (unless the OP clarifies what they want).

Comment: This wouldnt work as it would return everything that also has an AllDay flag set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make sure it falls within the Date portion of the Schedule.

```
var events = entity.Schedule
    .Where(x => x.Start.Date <= start.Date && start.Date <= x.End.Date)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
    .ThenBy(x => x.End)
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you have a list of ranges and you want to filter them, if they hit another range. Due to the fact that you compare two ranges, there are several possibilities which could happen:

1. Both ranges don't touch each other

   ```
   |---candidate---|
                       |---filter---|
   ```
2. The end of the candidate matches the begin of the filter

   ```
   |---candidate---|
                   |---filter---|
   ```
3. The end of the candidate falls within the filter

   ```
   |---candidate---|
                 |---filter---|
   ```
4. The candidate encapsulates the filter

   ```
   |---candidate---|
     |---filter---|
   ```
5. The candidate exactly matches the filter

   ```
   |---candidate---|
   |----filter-----|
   ```
6. The candidate falls within the filter

   ```
     |---candidate---|
   |------filter-------|
   ```
7. The begin of the candidate falls within the filter

   ```
      |---candidate---|
   |---filter---|
   ```
8. The begin of the candidate matches the end of the filter

   ```
                |---candidate---|
   |---filter---|
   ```

Please specify which of these possibilities you like to see and which not. Some cases are quite trivial to answer (like 1, 5 and 6), but all others are really depending on the specific use-case. So please tell which cases should be matched and we can create the desired where clause.